# Make Badge Width Consistent

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, design

Personally, I think the [/badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page is a bit...unsightly.

Adding `min-width: 10em` to the `badge` class gives it much more consistency:

[image]

I propose this be adjusted site-wide, both for the badges page, and the user profile page.

I'd be really curious to hear reasons this *shouldn't* be changed.

---

One potential issue: tag badges. Generally they're shorter than 10em (none of the top 200 tags break), but obviously longer ones *do* exist. Using `min-width` instead of just `width` should still improve the vast majority of badge views regardless, and if a couple poke out a bit further, is that any worse than the current look?

Comment: *"I'd be really curious to hear reasons this shouldn't be changed."* - And I'd be equally as interested in hearing reasons why it *should* be changed. You haven't really provided any (past this looks ugly to me), and I personally think the min-width thing looks even worse.

Comment: My reason is laid out in the first two sentences. It's ugly now, and looks better consistent. Clearly that's subjective though. But by all means vote
 with your votes :)

Comment: Please don't. The ocean of blank on the right side looks *butt* ugly.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n0D4r.png Which one do you like better? The right one looks ***really*** ugly here.

Comment: @animuson +1, should turn that comment into an answer imo ;)

Answer (score 0):

While I can understand your POV, in the end the status quo is more *readable* , whereas in the redo I'm almost trying to continue the sentence … "Altruist… once upon a time lived?"

I think it depends on how you're seeing it, I think you see the badge as an image. But I see it as just text.

That said, I tried my hand at some kind of compromise... which is to center text inside the badge-box(which makes the long-names a taller box). This reduces the "to be continued" effect I mentioned above:

[image]

Comment: Funny you'd say that about image vs text. I'm not a programmer. I spend my days making pretty pictures. It makes sense that I'd see it as an image, and that programmers would see it as text. That's fascinating.

Comment: It's a nice attempt, but my point is about consistency. Making one taller is even worse. It also seems to have just added a unilateral 40 pixel gap on the left? Centering shouldn't require a wrap; `10em` was enough for all the badges to fit on one line, regardless of justification

Comment: @mhlester  - thanks !! :-)  Yeah I know what you mean. Well, I'm out of decent ideas. My apologies about all those DV's - this is a good post!!

Comment: Not at all. It's only a good suggestion if people agree. It's clear they don't, so it should remain the way it is. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: @mhlester - You're very welcome!! And Thank You!